# What is the name (if any) for this kind of tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have this tree which, for each node, has *exactly* 10 childnodes (0-9). Each node has some associated data (say, for example, a name and a tag and a color) which, I guess, isn't important for this question. Each of the childnodes has exactly 10 childnodes. A node can be `null` (which 'ends' the branch') or contain another node.

To visualize what I'm talking about I made this diagram (fear my paintz0r skillz!):
[image: Tree]

A black box is a `null-node`. A white box is a node which contains data and childnodes. As you can see, even the root, each node has exactly 10 childnodes. Because of simplicity and to keep the diagram sane I have drawn some nodes very tiny but you can imagine these tiny nodes being the same.

This structure allows me to traverse a path consisting of digits very quickly: a path of `47352` would lead me down the "orange path" to the final destination; `4->7->3->5` where the final `2` cannot be resolved because that last one is a null-node (although colored red) and contains no childnodes.

My question is pretty simple actually: what is this kind of tree called? I have gone through all trees on [Wikipedia's Tree (data structure) lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) and the closest I (think I) could get is the [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) and/or [K-ary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree). Along those lines of reasoning my tree would be called a Dectree, Decitree, 10-ary tree or 10-way tree or something. But there might be a better name for this. So: anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[K-ary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree)** with K=10

> In graph theory, a k-ary tree is a rooted tree in which each node has
> no more than k children
>
> It is also sometimes known as a k-way tree, an N-ary tree, or an M-ary
> tree. A binary tree is the special case where k=2.

Answer (score 0):

This is something like [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).